# The jquery function load() doesn't load correctly dojo content

Tags: jquery, dojo

In my web site I've multiple calls of the jquery function load().

We can sumarize like this :

1) In My index page calls this  `$('#mainFrame').load('/antoherPage.jsp');`
 I insert this code in the head of my index page :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"/><script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dojo/dojo.xd.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad: true,locale: 'en'"></scipt>
```

2) In my another page, it calls this `$('#main').load('/Form.jsp');`

3) In 'Form', I've some field from dijit : dijit.form.ValidationTextBox, ...

```
<input  dojoType='dijit.form.ValidationTextBox'></input>
```

In my index page, I've this :

Basically, if I load the page Form.jsp, everyhting is correctly displayed. However, when I load my index page, everyhting is not correctly diplayed in the Form.

I'd like to know if I need to write some special code into the form page or into another page. Maybe the multiple calls of the load is not accepted by dojo/dijit?

Thank you very much

Bat

Comment: when you mix jquery and dojo first thing come to my mind is `conflict` and for that there is `noConflict` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ may be it'll help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you ajax load a page, you need to call `dojo.parser.parse()`.  Dojo has no idea that you are loading another page via ajax, and thus the parser doesn't know to look through the new content for dijit widgets in markup.

You'll need to `dojo.require('dojo.parser')` as well.

EDIT:  looking at the jquery load docs, a more full featured example would be:

```
$('#main').load('/Form.jsp', function() {
//make sure we have the dojo.parser component pulled in, although it should probably be done in <head>
dojo.require('dojo.parser');
dojo.parser.parse();
});
```

As always, the dojo.parser component should be loaded prior to the execution of that ajax call

Comment: also take a look at Alex Cheng's answer for a similiar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214794/reload-dojo-widgets-after-ajax-request/7226096#7226096)

Comment: does jquery.load pull in and execute script references from HEAD, or does it just do a substitution of the BODY text?  If the latter, you'll have to do something about those as well, like additional dojo.require calls.

Comment: I'm not much of a jquery guy, but from the docs (http://api.jquery.com/load/) it looks like it just swaps html that comes from the given URL.